# Joomla: how to use the site default text editor for the module Textarea parameter field type

Tags: joomla, module, wysiwyg, text-editor

I want to use the site default text editor like TinyMCE or JCE as the editor in the Module Textarea parameter field type. Will that be possible anyhow?
I am using Joomla 2.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.joomla.org/Editor_form_field_type
I have got the solution using the parameter type as "editor"